# Написание приложения для винды из linux

Tags: golang, gui, кросс-компиляция

Попросили написать программу для создания 3д модели по входным данным. Долго не думая написал на python (flask) + js как веб-сервис. Но теперь хотят чтобы это запускалось с компа локально. Ставить клиенту python и учить запускать gunicorn не хочется, поэтому нужно переписать на чем нибудь компилируемом. C++, Java не вариант, т.к. долго вникать, да и хочется, чтобы программа запускалась сразу без установки java и т.д. Думаю насчет golang, может есть еще какие-то варианты? (Важно чтобы можно было разрабатывать с линукса и компилить под винду, т.е. кроссплатформенность. Не охота ставить винду из-за простенького приложения)

Comment: Если Java и C++ не варианты, зачем вы указываете эти теги?

Comment: Извините, не знаю что еще указать

Comment: @As33v тут все абстрактно написано. уточните входящий тип данных. хоть немного информации.

Comment: На вход эксель файл с маленькой таблицей, на основе которой строится 3д модель, которую можно вращать. Оставил все на питоне (с веб интерфейсом) и решил просто упаковать его в exe при помощи pyinsaller